# Sencha Touch mask ondisclosure

Tags: extjs, touch

I'm creating a list with an onDisclosure event. When I click on the onDisclosure icon, I do this:

```
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'newpanel',
        title: record.info(),
        data: record.getData()
    });
```

But due the fact that "newpanel" is very big, it takes 6/7 seconds to show me the panel.

Therefore, I tried to add a mask like this:

```
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
        xtype: 'loadmask',
        message: 'Loading...'
    });


    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'newpanel',
        title: record.info(),
        data: record.getData()
    });



    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
```

But due to the fact that Javascript is asynchronous, these code lines doesnt run on the specified order. First he pushes the new panel, than we wait 6/7 seconds and then he sets the mask to true and immediatly to false, so we cannot see the mask.

Does someone has any ideas about how to solve this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big could that panel be? I've seen huge component compositions render almost instantaneously. There is most probably a problem in your `newpanel` implementation, like rendering multiple times in a loop or something. You should review your code to eliminate that.

As for the question you asked... You must give some time to Ext for rendering the mask before the Javascript thread gets frozen by your intensive code. For that, you need to defer the creation of your panel like this:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
    xtype: 'loadmask',
    message: 'Loading...'
});

var me = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    me.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'newpanel',
        title: record.info(),
        data: record.getData()
    });

    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false); 
}, 100); // 100ms should be enough for rendering a loading mask
```

Unfortunately, even if that will make the mask become visible, the UI will still freeze, and so will animated GIFs (e.g. loading icon).

In order to avoid that, you would need to run your intensive code in a separated thread, that is by spawning a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers). But I don't think it would even be possible to render Ext components from a worker...

So, in last resort, you could repeat the deferring strategy used in my example in your big panel. If you can identify some intensive code blocks that can be isolated in there, then by deferring their execution for a few milliseconds, you would free some processing time for handling UI events, animating GIFs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, rixo! My new panel is not just a panel, but a tabpabel with 6 tabs invoking 6 new panels. I've tried the implementation that you've mentioned but when I do
"this.getMain().push"
I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getMain'"
Because "this" inside the timeout function is different to "this" outside the timeout function. I tried to use "this.getParent()" or "this.up()", but no effect...

Comment: You're right, sorry. I fixed the example using closure. Alternatively, you can use `Ext.Function.defer` that let you manage the scope, instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: Yes, I think my brain was freezed, of course I had to do that! Thank you so much, it's perfect now!